# How to write if exist statement that would run a different select depending if it exists or not

Tags: sql, reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I am trying to convert a sql `if exists` statement into a SSRS valid format to run a report on CRM.

CRM report doesn't accept the report on upload if I have a `if exists` method, I'm having troubles figuring out what I can use in its place.

```
IF EXISTS(select * from dbo.FC where dbo.FC.ContactID in (select dbo.AV.so_contactid from dbo.AV))
begin
    select [STATEMENT 1]
    from dbo.AV CRMAF_so_AV join
         dbo.FC c 
        on CRMAF_so_AV.so_contactid = c.ContactID;
end
else
begin
    select [STATEMENT 2]
    from dbo.AV CRMAF_so_AV join
         dbo.FA c
         on CRMAF_so_AV.so_contactid = c.AccountID;

end;
```

I want to be able to either run the `select [STATEMENT 1]` if the condition is true else I want to run `select [STATEMENT 2]`

Comment: i cant give data as its sensitive but the result i expect would run a different select statement depending if the IF EXISTS returns anything, i'm just so unsure where or what to look for. SQL aint my strong point.

Comment: I still cannot get this to work, everything i'm trying keeps on getting errors when i try uploading the .rdl file to crm saying that something inside the .rdl file is invalid.

Comment: if somebody asks for sample data, it does not have to be real, just has to represent the same datatypes and context, just change names of people, companies, account names etc and put some random numbers in place of the real ones.

Comment: If this is a CRM report, SQL is not supported. What version of CRM is this for?

Comment: This is for CRM 8.2.2.112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this to work by doing a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN`.

```
select [STATEMENT 1 + 2 all columns needed]
from dbo.AV CRMAF_so_AV 
left join dbo.FC c on CRMAF_so_AV.so_contactid = c.ContactID;
left join dbo.FA a on CRMAF_so_AV.so_contactid = a.AccountID;
```

This now runs if its an account or a contact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

You have to put your entire statement in `@select1` and `@select1`.

```
declare @statement1 as varchar(max);
declare @statement2 as varchar(max);

SET @statement1 = 'SELECT 1'
SET @statement2 = 'SELECT 2'

IF EXISTS(select * from dbo.FC where dbo.FC.ContactID in (select dbo.AV.so_contactid from dbo.AV))

    BEGIN
        EXEC (@statement1)
    END

ELSE 

    BEGIN
        EXEC (@statement2)
    END
```

Comment: This still errors on uploading the .rdl file saying that its not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
WITH PreSelection AS (
  SELECT 
    AV.ID AS AVID, 
    (SELECT TOP(1) c.ContactID FROM dbo.FC c WHERE c.ContactID = AV.so_contactid) AS ContactID, 
    (SELECT TOP(1) c.ContactID FROM dbo.FA c WHERE c.AccountID = AV.so_contactid) AS AccountID 
  FROM dbo.AV
)

SELECT
  AVID,
  ISNULL(
    CASE WHEN ContactID IS NULL 
    THEN (SELECT TOP(1) AccountName FROM dbo.FA WHERE FA.AccountID = AccountID)
    ELSE (SELECT TOP(1) LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(FirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(LastName, ''))) FROM dbo.FC WHERE FC.ContactID = ContactID)
    END, '') AS ContactName
FROM PreSelection
```

Comment: Do i keep the exists? ie CASE WHEN EXISTS(...)

Comment: i'll give this a go and let you know, really apprechiate the help as its been very difficult getting any answers from searching

Comment: I still get an error when uploading this to the crm reports, saying that the .rdl file isnt valid

Comment: As you haven't posted the column names of your selection I just made up some for you and you have to translate them into the real names.

You also have to have the same number, type and order of columns in the THEN .... and the ELSE .... so SQLServer has a chance to build a table like result set.

If you need more help, post the CREATE Statements for tables AV, FA and FC.

Do you have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio installed to test your queries?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using if exists can you not get a count of records that meet the criteria and then if its 1 or greater run a different query as apposed to if it was equal to 0.

let me know if I am missing something what you are trying to achieve.

sorry i am unable to put comments due to having a new account so my reputation is low.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:
When SSRS evaluates query it expects the resluts to always have the same structure in terms of column names and types.

So you **CANNOT do** something like this..

```
IF @x=@y
    BEGIN
        SELECT Name, Age FROM employees
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT DeptID, DeptName, DeptEMpCOunt FROM departments
    END
```

... as this will return different types and column names and column counts.

**What you CAN DO is this..**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(resultType int, colA varchar(128), colB int, colC varchar(128), colD int)
IF @x=@y
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t(resultType, colA, ColB)
        SELECT 1 as resultType, Name, Age FROM employees
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t(resultType, colB, colC, colD)
        SELECT 2 AS resultType, DeptID, DeptName, DeptEmpCount FROM departments
    END

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Al we are doing is creating a table that can handle all variations of the data and putting the results into whatever columns can accommodate that data type.

This will always return the same data structure so SSRS will be happy, then you will need to handle which columns to display your data from based on what gets returned, hence why I added the result type to the results so you can test that from within the report.

Comment: Many thanks for this, this worked, after talking to a collegue i have sorted out the problem, i have done it instead of a JOIN i am doing LEFT JOIN on both the tables in the same select and running the report from all the data instead of the different selects.